# Please help me simplify the following code

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can anyone assist me in simplifying this working piece of jQuery? I've heard that forEach could help me there, but don't know how to use it.

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

$("div#accordion .panel:nth-child(1)").click(function(){
$(".changer .vc_column-inner").css("cssText", "background-image: url(wp-content/uploads/2016/04/WLDMCHPLAY-QF-FANS1-e1469784860667.jpg) !important;");
});

$("div#accordion .panel:nth-child(2)").click(function(){
$(".changer .vc_column-inner").css("cssText", "background-image: url(wp-content/uploads/2016/04/mountains-snow-cars-bentley-roads-vehicles-bentley-continental-bentley-continental-gt-front-angle-vi-2015.jpg) !important;");
});

$("div#accordion .panel:nth-child(3)").click(function(){
$(".changer .vc_column-inner").css("cssText", "background-image: url(wp-content/uploads/2016/04/1007.jpg) !important;");
});

}(jQuery));
</script>
```

Comment: I think you might mean `.css("background-image", "url()");`.

Comment: Nah, had to do it this way to include the "!important"

Comment: Would you move your solution to an answer box please? We try to keep Q&A separate here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simplify it using an array. Store the CSS property value in an array and update value based on element index (index can be get using [`index()`](https://api.jquery.com/index/) method).

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  // store URLs in an array for selecting based on the index
  var css = [
    "url(wp-content/uploads/2016/04/WLDMCHPLAY-QF-FANS1-e1469784860667.jpg) !important;",
    "url(wp-content/uploads/2016/04/mountains-snow-cars-bentley-roads-vehicles-bentley-continental-bentley-continental-gt-front-angle-vi-2015.jpg) !important;",
    "url(wp-content/uploads/2016/04/1007.jpg) !important;"
  ],
    // store the reference to the element for future reference 
  $ele = $("div#accordion .panel").click(function() {
    // get the css value based the index of clicked element
    // with help of referenced variable , here index means the position within the referenced selector
    // where `this` refer to the clicked element
    $(".changer .vc_column-inner").css("cssText", "background-image:" + css[$ele.index(this)]);
  });
}(jQuery));
```

Comment: okay so from what I understand here.

1. the var css is an array with the urls

2. you then declared a second var with the css selector

on click you target the css that needs to swap out the bg-image

could you explain the "css[$ele.index(this)]"

-- sorry I am still very new to this and I am just trying to learn

Comment: @SonyThePony :  the second one is just for the reference to get index

Comment: @SonyThePony `$ele.index(this)` - return the index of clicked element(`this`)` within the selector `$ele`(reference of `$("div#accordion .panel")` ) .... afterwards selecting element from `css` array .... if first element clicked `$ele.index(this)` returns `0` ( since index starts from `0`) and getting `css[0]`

Comment: AH!! THANKS tested with: console.log("me", $("div#accordion .panel").index(this) ); I understand what you did there, very smart. THANKS!!!

Comment: @SonyThePony : glad to help you :)

Comment: Because of the !important in the variable the code did not work... so I updated it to:  $(".changer .vc_column-inner").css("cssText", "background-image:" + css[$ele.index(this)]);

Answer (score 0):

*(Posted on behalf of the OP)*.

Thanks to Pranav C Balan I came to the final answer of:

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

  var css = [
    "url(wp-content/uploads/2016/04/WLDMCHPLAY-QF-FANS1-e1469784860667.jpg)  !important;",
    "url(wp-content/uploads/2016/04/mountains-snow-cars-bentley-roads-vehicles-bentley-continental-bentley-continental-gt-front-angle-vi-2015.jpg)  !important;",
    "url(wp-content/uploads/2016/04/1007.jpg) !important;"
  ],

  $ele = $("div#accordion .panel").click(function() {
    $(".changer .vc_column-inner").css("cssText", "background-image:" + css[$ele.index(this)]);
  });
}(jQuery));
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't apply images from jQuery. Instead use classes in CSS and add classes through jQuery.

Advantage of using such solution is you don't have to change the JS if you want to add or change the image.

Following code will generate the classes with index.

Apply css to them like this

**CSS Code**

```
.backGroud0{
background:url('wp-content/uploads/2016/04/WLDMCHPLAY-QF-FANS1-e1469784860667.jpg');
}
.backGroud1{
background:url('wp-content/uploads/2016/04/mountains-snow-cars-bentley-roads-vehicles-bentley-continental-bentley-continental-gt-front-angle-vi-2015.jpg');
}
.backGroud2{
background:url('wp-content/uploads/2016/04/1007.jpg');
}
```

**JS CODE**

```
jQuery( ".div#accordion .panel" ).each( function(index, value){
 jQuery( this ).click( function(){
   jQuery( this ).addClass( "backGround" + index );
 });
});
```